# If $ \sup(A)=\sup(B)$ and $\inf(A)=\inf(B)$ does that mean that $A=B$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

If $A=B$ then its easy to show that $\sup(A)=\sup(B)$ and $\inf(A)=\inf(B)$. However, is the opposite of this statement also true?

i.e. If $\sup(A)=\sup(B)$ and $\inf(A)=\inf(B)$ then $A=B$?

Comment: Try it ft for a few cases, say where $A$ is finite, but $B$ is not

Comment: Try $A=[0,1]$, $B=\{0,1\}$.

Comment: $A=\{1,2,3\},\ B=\{1,3\} $

Comment: Obviously the answer is no. Take $\{ 0,1 \} , (0,1) , [0,1]$ as an example.

Comment: The sups and the infs tell you about the limits of the sets; nothing about the "interiors" of the sets at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and the reason is that this information about the extreme values of the sets, does not say anything about the other values of the sets that are between these extreme values (or bounds). Some examples

1. $A=[0,1]$ and $B=(0,1)$,
2. $A={-1}\cup[0,1]\cup {2}$ and $B[-1,2]$
3. $A=(0,1) \cup (2, +\infty)$ and $B=[0,+\infty)$,
4. $A=\left\{\frac1n: n \in \mathbb N\right\}$ and $B=[0,1]$,
5. $A=[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ and $B=[0,1]\cap \mathbb {R\setminus Q}$.
6. $\ldots$ many (many) more.

But, if $\sup A= \sup B$ and $\inf A=\inf B$ holds and you know that the sets $A, B$ have other properties in common: for example that they are both open connected intervals, then you can perhaps (in this special case) infer that they are the same.